# How to use focusrite ISA 220 with 3rd gen focusrite scarlet 2i2?

Tags: production

Recently got my hands on a Focusrite ISA 220 and want to know how best to hook it up to my current focusrite scarlet 2i2 3rd Gen interface?

I’ve read lots of conflicting opinions online about this even though I’m sure outboard pre’s are commonly used with these types of interface? I had assumed it was just a matter of plugging output of pre into a channel on interface with a 1/4” trs and just being sensible with the gain.

I had also assumed that it could be more beneficial running through two pre’s as i could get nice warm sound with the first and ensure plenty of headroom with the second and probably produce different sounds than i can currently going with a mic straight into interface. however this could be very flawed thinking haha.

Thanks for reading and any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: “I had assumed it was just a matter of plugging output of pre into a channel on interface with a 1/4” trs and just being sensible with the gain.” Can you tell us what happened when you did this? It should have worked